# How to store cards when game boxes don't have slots for them

Tags: storage

I have two board games which use a lot of cards, but their boxes don't have dedicated space to store them in an ordered manner and whenever I'd like to play them again I have to start with sorting all the cards by type.

How can I store these cards so they don't fly all over the box? The exact two games I have in mind are [Lord of the Rings LCG](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/77423/the-lord-of-the-rings-the-card-game) and [Dragon's Ordeal](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/65592/dragons-ordeal), but I'm looking for a solution which I could apply to a greater variety of dimensions. I am not from the UK or US so I'd prefer more generic items, because it might be difficult/too expensive to purchase stuff from Amazon or online shops.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hair Bands**

[image: hair bands]

Similar to using rubber bands, but they don't deteriorate and stick to the cards over time. If possible get metal free ones, rather than the type on the right - less likely to catch on the cards.

**Small Cardboard Boxes**

[image: Cardboard Box]

Have a look around your house, you'll probably find something that's the right size. Plasters often come in boxes that are a good fit for cards.

Comment: The more tension the hairbands have, the more they distort the cards. But the less tension they have, the less they keep the cards in place. I would not recommend this method unless you have little concern for the condition of your cards.

Answer (score 7):

- **Rubber bands** - [Extremely cheap solution](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/369756/geeks-who-dont-use-rubber-bands-or-plastic-bags). Allows you to group cards of a similar type together. Over a long period of time though, the rubber will crack and may even stick to your cards. If you sleeve your cards this is of minor concern.
- **Plastic Sandwich bags** - If you submit your games to high humidity, these do not "breath" and may cause moisture damage.
- **Custom Dividers** - You can create [custom dividers](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/1392281/the-lord-of-the-rings-the-card-game) for your game boxes by cutting cardboard, chip board, foam core, or wood into horizontal and vertical slats with notches. When pieced together, they should hold the cards in place.
- **Custom Tuck boxes** - Many games have custom tuck boxes that have been designed by fans. Check the BGG file section. If not, you can always use a deck box for Magic the Gathering or similar card game.

Comment: A small hole punch would probably help plastic bags breath. Just make sure to remember to punch the hole *before* putting cards in them. There are also bags with hole already in them.

Answer (score 5):

I bought a bunch of these grip seal bags in various sizes. I did buy these from Amazon, but have seen them in stationery shops if you prefer not to get them shipped.

These ones for cards cost me £1.34 GBP with free shipping for 100 (1.3 pence each). Unless eBay/Amazon shipping is super extortionate for you, I think they are worth the investment; I've found them great for storing decks of cards as well as other components.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B0026DGN00/ref=wms_ohs_product?ie=UTF8&psc=1
[image: grip seal bags]

Answer (score 2):

If you do not find tuckboxes for your favorite game at boardgamegeek.com already, you may always easly [create your own boxes here.](https://www.cpforbes.net/tuckbox/tuckbox.cgi)

Answer (score 2):

I use [Hugo's Amazing Tape](https://www.amazingtape.com/).

It works similarly to plastic wrap; but it doesn't tear like that does. And you can either re-wrap it around the deck each time, or slide the wrapped ring on and off the cards (unless they are sleeved, then it won't slide).

I use the 1/2 inch, but I think the 1 inch would actually work better.

Very similarly, a friend of mine actually uses bondage tape for this. It also works in the exact same way, but is at least 2 inches wide I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Amazing tape or ziplock bags. A craft store should have bags in various handy sizes — look in the beading section.

Edit to add: I also bought online a tiny hole punch. Small enough holes that I use it on bits bags and don’t worry about small game pieces falling out.